# Create and execute the cron job in PHP

Tags: php, cron

There are similar thread, I already went through. They don't clear my doubts please!

refresh.php

```
<?php

echo "This code will run every minute";
if(count!=1)
 count+=1;
else
 $count = 1;

echo $count;
?>
```

cron.php

```
<?php
    exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n30 1 * * * /opt/lamt/htdocs/refresh.php" | crontab -'); //to run at 1:30 am        
?>
```

1. How to run this at 10:30 pm ?
2. How to execute `cron.php` ??

Am I going in currect direction?

Comment: I think you must call your file using `php -f /opt/lamt/htdocs/refresh.php`

Comment: "contab -e" for editing your cron schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open shell and type this:

```
command="php /opt/lamt/htdocs/refresh.php"
job="30 22 * * * $command"
cat <(fgrep -i -v "$command" <(crontab -l)) <(echo "$job") | crontab -
```

The above creates a cronjob that executes `/opt/lamt/htdocs/refresh.php` every day at `22.30`.

```
command="php /opt/lamt/htdocs/refresh.php"
job="30 10 * * * $command"
cat <(fgrep -i -v "$command" <(crontab -l)) <(echo "$job") | crontab -
```

The above creates a cronjob that executes `/opt/lamt/htdocs/refresh.php` every day at `10.30`.

This is the correct `crontab` syntax:

```
# * * * * *  command to execute
# ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬ ┬
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ │
# │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
# │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
# │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
# │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
# └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Comment: Source? what if I want to execute twice in a day? 10:30 pm  and am too

Comment: @Programming_crazy I've updated my answer, check it out.

Comment: @Tuga: thanks, above Do i need to execute above command directory into terminal? no need for any extra file i.e. cron.php? right?

Answer (score 2):

Open your linux terminal, then write a command:

```
crontab -e
```

Text-editor will open.
Copy this line there:

```
30 22 * * * php -f /opt/lamt/hdocs/refresh.php
```

Save.
You don't need no "exec" in your PHP code.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need **cron.php**, follow my lead :

Try this command :

```
nano /etc/crontab
```

And add this line in the file :

```
30 22 * * * username  /usr/bin/php  /opt/lamt/hdocs/refresh.php
```

Comment: No need to restart the `crond` service

Comment: Are you sure ? let me check

Comment: Check it here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Comment: 1 up for your revision

Answer (score 1):

Cron in windows: 
[Cron in windows](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx) 
Cron in Unix:
[Cron in Unix](http://www.rahul.net/raithel/MyBackPages/crontab.html)

In `cron.php` you should enter just php code