# running php file with crontab

Tags: php, cron

I have the following problem:

I'm using the latest crontab version with win 9x/nt

I put the crontab file, the exe file and the log file into the root of my website (aruba linux)

I put the following code inside the crontab file

```
0 24 * * * php example.php
```

In the `example.php` I make an insert

I've tried to do the operation going to the page and it's working fine.

However the crontab doesn't start, even modifying the minutes and hours like * *. In the log file there's written nothing.

I've read that the "php" voice represents the folder in which php is located.

How can know where is it on my website?

Do  have to ask to the service of the server or what?

Comment: You need to specify the full path of `example.php` in your server. Otherwise, crontab does not know where to find it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create and execute the cron job in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21232247/create-and-execute-the-cron-job-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/myscript.php

1. The first path is the location of your php binary
2. The second path is the location of your php script.

Comment: what is /usr/local/bin/php? i don't have these folders on my website

Comment: Look for where your php binary is located.  Why the down vote? Seems a bit harsh.

Comment: How can i know where the php binary is located? I can't find it

Comment: wait a second... i don't have caught really well so please be more specific. i printed the php_info() and the __FILE__ and the results were /usr/local/bin/php & /web/htdocs/www.example.it/home/ so i wrote this on the crontab * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /web/htdocs/www.example.it/home/example.php but nothing happened. where is the etc folder located? i've put the three files (log,exe,crontab) into my root, i've tried to create a folder called etc and i put the files there but nothing happened. what's the problem with this?

Comment: Please try the following to confirm you have the correct path in the crontab.   `ls -d $PWD/example.php`   What path does it show?

Comment: where do i have to try this?

Comment: using your unix terminal navigate to the folder where example.php lives. Then type `ls -d $PWD/example.php`

Answer (score 0):

Just specify the absolute path for `example.php`. 
Otherwise crontab will never find it to execute.

To find it, you can use `echo __FILE__;` so, you'll get the full path for script.

Comment: even if example.php is in the root as the crontab file and the exe?

Answer (score 0):

Try the absolute path of the php file, and the absolute path of the php command :

```
0 24 * * * /usr/bin/php /full/path/to/example.php
```

if `/usr/bin/php` is not working, try `which php` and replace `/usr/bin/php` with the result of this command .

the default folder for crontab is set in the `/etc/crontab` file in :

```
HOME=/path/
```

and you can change it to your default web root, this way you can use just `example.php`, but if only you have root access .